# Creating an exponential scale

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

Good morning,

I am trying to create an exponential scale for attributing values in a scoring model.

Here is the function I was thinking of using:

y = z^x

Where:

y = Score
X = Risk assessment value that goes from 1 to 10

Now here is my thing. I need to make sure that the minimum value of Y is 25 and its maximum value is 300. 
I don't care what the value of z is. 
X has values between 1 and 10
I need to make a function so that Y fits my minimum and maximum requirements:

Min --> 25 = z^1
Max --> 300 = z^10

Y can take any value between 25 and 300 when the x is comprised between 2 and 9.

I guess I should create a systems of equations?

Thanks,
Bernardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you're asking for is not possible. If $25 = z^1$, this implies $z=25$. But this does not satisfy $300 = z^{10}$.

What you are looking for (I guess) is an equation of the form $$y = C \cdot z^x$$
with the conditions

$$25 = C \cdot z \leftrightarrow C=\frac{25}{z}$$

and

$$300 = C \cdot z^{10} \leftrightarrow C=\frac{300}{z^{10}}$$

Setting the two equations equal to each other we get:

$$\frac{25}{z} = \frac{300}{z^{10}} \leftrightarrow z^9 = \frac{300}{25}$$

with the solution $z=(\frac{300}{25})^{\frac{1}{9}} \approx 1.32$. Substitute the value for $z$ into one of the equations above to obtain the value of $C \approx 19$.

Comment: Thank you very much, yeah that coefficient C is clearly needed.It's been a while since I worked out math, I'm having issues tracing back how you got to (300/25)^1/9. Could you please walk me through if you have the time?

Comment: @Bernardo I added some steps. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Yes, very much so. Appreciated. So now I don't have to ask another question if I've to do the same but with different numbers :)